# Bulk Add All (*.js) or (*.css) files to service worker cache on install

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, offline-caching

If I have a service worker registered with the doc root ( / ) as its scope,
And my Document Layout is like so:

- Doc-Root

  - Includes

    - JS

      - PHP/JS /HTML Files
    - CSS

      - PHP/CSS Files
    - Typography

How Do I Add All JS Only/CSS Only files to the service worker cache **On Install** and exclude other extensions Under each Directory?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a utility like [sw-precache](https://npmjs.com/package/sw-precache) that will take care of generating the service-worker.js file.

Here's an example from one of my projects. You can change the glob pattern to fit your needs.

```
const swPrecache = require('sw-precache')
swPrecache.write('./public/service-worker.js', {
    root: './public/',
    staticFileGlobs: ['./public/**/*'],
    stripPrefix: './public/'
})
```